# Fortify scanner outputs

Tags: java, fortify

I'm using fortify 16.11 to analyze a project which is structured like:

```
root/
    module1/
    module2/
    ...
```

When I scan the whole project I found that I have some security issues in `root/module1` but when scanning `root/module1` only I cannot find those issues.

Please, can anyone explain to me why I'm getting different results for different scans?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Fortify must build a complete call graph to determine a finding and I believe it errors on the side of no finding to prevent any "false positives". If your module 1 finding's call graph/stack trace comes from something out of the root, then just scanning module 1 will never find the finding because the root isn't being scanned.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. what do you mean by finding? also, I think that when fortify runs a scan, and it finds a suspect security issue it will try to find the source causing this problem. if it can resolve the source in `module1` scope it's Ok, if it resolves it in `root` scope we should find the issue in `mosule1` scan, and when fortify cannot resolve the source we should find the issues in both scans. What do you think, please?

Comment: To use your words, I'm saying a finding would be a "suspect security issue".

You want to make sure the scans are done from the application entry point. If that's module 1, then you shouldn't need to scan the root. But Fortify can't build a complete stack trace without starting at the beginning. Hope that makes sense.